# CHEF commands help ,

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

How can I write this command in chef ?

```
/home/vagrant$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm (->enter)
```

I tried...

```
execute "foo" do
 command "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
 action :run
end
```

in short, how can I write a simple command in chef? not installing something. thanks!!!

Comment: I also tried the 


bash "foo" do


 code "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"


end 


Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[foo]'

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something Chef supports. `source` is a shell builtin, not a command, and it would have no effect on Ruby anyway has that isn't a Ruby script, it is a shell script. You can use a bash resource like this:

```
bash 'do the needful' do
  code <<-EOH
    source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
    foo
  EOH
end
```

Comment: thank you sir!!!!
how about typing this command <<echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc>> is the method the same? or i can now use the execute command action run method?

Comment: No, I don't really know what you mean by that but no combination of those things would work.

Comment: @coderanger I think he wish to add the `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` to his `.bashrc` file. In this case the user should be supplied in the bash resource (`user vagrant` IIRC). @JustineGumba could you confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

Aw forgot to get back here:

```
bash 'do the needful' do
  user "target user"
  code <<-EOH
    echo 'source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm' >> ${HOME}/.bashrc
  EOH
end
```

I'm a little unsure on what $HOME would give in this case, maybe you'll have to specifiy the full path like /home/"target user"/.bashrc.

give it a try