# RVM, chef, default ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm, vagrant, chef-infra

please tell me the easiest way to use the install rvm and use the ruby version as default.
mine is 
bash "foo" do

```
       cwd "/home/user"
       code <<-EOH
       curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
       rvm user gemsets
       type rvm | head -n 1
       EOH
       end
```

bash "rvm ruby" do

```
user "root"
cwd "/home/uesr"
code <<-EOH
echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc
rvm install 2.1.2
rvm --default use 2.1.2
EOH
```

end

PLEASE tell me how to use it as default. or give me other way to do this, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [CHEF commands help ,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756486/chef-commands-help)

Comment: Im sure that my code is right but chef doesn't accept the code "rvm --default use 2.1.2" so Im looking for another it so that rvm will use it as default. but using chef

Comment: Chef use its own embedded version of ruby if you installed it with omnibus package. using rvm on top of it won't do anything as the chef-client 'binary' use the embedded and not the system nor the overrided rvm ruby.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer as it will be too long for a comment

```
bash "rvm ruby" do
  user "root"
  cwd "/home/uesr"
  code <<-EOH
    echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc
    rvm install 2.1.2
    rvm --default use 2.1.2
  EOH
end
```

Why are you giving a cwd /home/user (I'll assume its a typo here) ? you'll be running as root and the only write will be done in ~/.rvmrc which has good changes to got to /root (~ will expand to home directory).

What you try to accomplish is unclear (setting a ruby env for root or changing chef ruby env ?)

You may have a better chance with: https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/rvm

Answer (score 0):

Using [librarian-chef](https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian-chef) this is much easier.

1. `$ gem install librarian-chef`
2. `$ librarian-chef init`
3. add the following to your generated Cheffile `cookbook 'rvm', :git => 'git://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm.git', :ref => 'v0.9.2'`
4. `vagrant plugin install vagrant-librarian-chef`
5. `
   config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
       chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks"]
       ...
       chef.add_recipe 'rvm::user'
       ...

   ```
   chef.json = {
       rvm: {
           rvmrc: {
               rvm_autolibs_flag: "disabled"
           },
       user_installs: [{
           rubies: ['2.1.2'],
           default_ruby: 'ruby-2.1.2',
           user: 'vagrant',
           code: 'rvm use 2.1.2',
           global_gems: [{name: 'rake'}, {name: 'bundler'}]
       }]
   }
   ```

   end
   `
6. `vagrant up`

That should provision your VM with RVM installed on the vagrant user. Change your user install json settings as you see fit.

Comment: thanks! i should start using chef libraries and study them for better results.